# Sitecore EXM Security Issues

Tags: exm, permissions

Hide the create list column in the sitecore exm for particular users.

We tried to add restrictions in core database the text is hiding still it showing the icon.
Is there any way to hide the icon also.
[image]

Comment: Which item have you changed access to in core database?

Comment: ListFromFile Item: /sitecore/client/Applications/ECM/Component/Navigation/Primary Navigation/PageSettings/HyperlinkButtons/ListFromFile     and ListFromFileBylineText item: /sitecore/client/Applications/ECM/Component/Navigation/Primary Navigation/PageSettings/Text/ListFromFileBylineText

Comment: Couple thoughts here. This isnt a "Security Issue". I would reword the title. Secondly, those menu items are really all about ListManager, not EXM. If you look in List Manager you see the same options, just titled differently. I believe List Manager does have roles to control access to List Manager functions, but it wont hide the menu in EXM. As Marek mentions in his answer, any solution to hide is hacky and not recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong but I'm afraid that what you want to achieve is not possible.

The items which you changed access rights to are only `HyperlinkButton Parameters` item and `Text Parameters` item which means they hold text of the button, click action and help text.

The whole button consist of more components:

[image]

In frontend, I would use Sitecore personalization rules to hide certain components for chosen users. But it's Sitecore backend and from what I remember, personalization rules are not even executed there.

I tried to use Sitecore Rocks plugin to hide rendering with `where true (action always executed)` rule but it changed nothing.

And the image which is displayed comes from another component and links to a Sitecore icon. I downloaded the icon, uploaded it to media library, removed read access rights for an user and changed the image url to ID of the uploaded media library item, and that was the only way to hide an image which worked for me. But I could still see empty space there:

[image]

I don't like the solution. It's hacky and it doesn't look good. But it's the only one I found.